# Ajax not working on iphone but working on pc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropdown, onchange

I have a dropdown and when I select an option I run one ajax call, on pc is working as expected but on iPhone is not triggering the ajax, it goes to the function and I know this because I added alerts.
When i click 13,14,15 is not working. At 9,10,11,12 is working.

[image]

```
 <div class="row" id="type">
     Selected type:  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GymType, listItems, new { id = "GymType", onchange = "getBookTime();" })
  </div>
   <div id="timesList" style="display:none;margin:auto">
     Selecte time: <select id="states_ddl" name="states_ddl" class="cs3 input-small" > </select>
   </div>

 function getBookTime(e) {
     
        var selectedtype = $('#GymType').val();
        alert(selectedtype);
        var selectedDate = $('#date').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false, //This makes the JQuery below wait until $.ajax() call is finished
            cache: false,
            headers: { "cache-control": "no-cache" },
            url: '/Home/GetBookTime/',
            data: { date: selectedDate, type: selectedtype },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.message != undefined) {
                    alert(data.message);
                    $('#error').show();
                    document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML = data.message;
                }
                else {
                    alert(data);
                    $('#error').hide();
                    $("#timesList").show();
                    var options = $("#states_ddl");
                    options.empty();
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        options.append($("<option />").val(item).text(item));

                    });

                }
                $("#submitbtn").show();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        })


    }
```

Comment: no error message?

Comment: no error message. Nothing..

Comment: Try remove the alert and see, because the alert will block further execution. also make it async not sync.

Comment: I updated my question. when i click 13,14,15 is not working only